# Create a directory with mkdir from broad

Tags: command-line, bash

I am using ubuntu 11.10 and I am trying to create a directory in my home folder from another place without changing any directory.
The way I am currently using from it is :

```
cd ~
mkdir My_directory_name
```

but I don't want to use cd command and or any changing directory command. I googled my problem and I didn't find any thing. please help me !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should execute the command `mkdir ~/My_directory_name` which will create the directory in your home from any place.
Of course that you can do it for any other directory and not only to home - `mkdir <path>/<new_dir_name>` Where the <path> is absolute or relative path to the directory where you want <new_dir_name> to be created.

Comment: the command I used is : `mkdir "$PATH""/""$PROJECT_NAME"` but I got this error :  mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games/PROJECT_NAME': No such file or directory

Comment: @reza That's because the variable $PATH is not a single directory path. It's a list of directories separated by ':'.

Comment: when I make mkdir <foldername> the terminal says unexpected newline. why for you is it good?

Comment: @kouty You shouldn't type the < and > characters. So to create a directory named 'dirname' you should type `mkdir dirname`